# Customized pgf plot marks

Tags: tikz-pgf

I recently learned about the possibility to create custom plot marks using the `\pgfdeclareplotmark` option. However, from browsing the manual, the usage is not entirely clear to me.

I would like to have a marker style for crossed-out circles. Here's what I came up with:

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{xo}{%
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfplotmarksize}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-1.2\pgfplotmarksize}{-1.2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.2\pgfplotmarksize}{1.2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-1.2\pgfplotmarksize}{1.2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.2\pgfplotmarksize}{-1.2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
```

This already works nicely, but I'd like to customize this a bit more:

- I want the cross-mark to have a color different from the circle, preferably such that it can be given as an argument.
- It would be nice to have the lines of the cross to be drawn a bit more squiggly, possibly akin to the cross mark (`\ding{55}`).

Here's an MWE, showing what my current attempt looks like (and how the cross-mark would ideally look like).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{xo}{%
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfplotmarksize}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-1.2\pgfplotmarksize}{-1.2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.2\pgfplotmarksize}{1.2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-1.2\pgfplotmarksize}{1.2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{1.2\pgfplotmarksize}{-1.2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]
      \addplot[smooth,mark=xo,black] plot coordinates {
        (0,2)
        (2,3)
        (3,1)
      };
      \node[anchor=west] at (0.2,0.5) {Can you make it look like an \textcolor{red}\xmark{}?};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Put the new X on top of the existing via `\pgfnode` ?

Comment: How can I make sure that the X is always nicely centered about the circle and scales correctly if I use a larger marker size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping all the conversion magic, the `pgfnode` version suggested by [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) of course also works:

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{xo}{%
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfplotmarksize}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
  \pgfnode{rectangle}{center}{\resizebox{2.5\pgfplotmarksize}{2.5\pgfplotmarksize}{\color{red}\ding{55}}}{}{}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `Inkscape` and the glorious `svg2tikz` extension (as well as converting back and forth the image a couple of times), I was able to come up with a solution:

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{xo}{%
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfplotmarksize}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
  \path[draw=none,fill=red] (-1.2410\pgfplotmarksize,-1.6636\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (-1.3125\pgfplotmarksize,-1.5121\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (-1.3142\pgfplotmarksize,-1.3244\pgfplotmarksize) .. (-1.2170\pgfplotmarksize,-1.1831\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (-0.9789\pgfplotmarksize,-0.7541\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (-0.6560\pgfplotmarksize,-0.3820\pgfplotmarksize) .. (-0.3522\pgfplotmarksize,0.0007\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (-0.4597\pgfplotmarksize,0.3080\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (-0.5793\pgfplotmarksize,0.6114\pgfplotmarksize) .. (-0.6749\pgfplotmarksize,0.9226\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (-0.7289\pgfplotmarksize,1.0582\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (-0.5838\pgfplotmarksize,1.1276\pgfplotmarksize) .. (-0.4725\pgfplotmarksize,1.0881\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (-0.4126\pgfplotmarksize,1.1418\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (-0.3420\pgfplotmarksize,1.1794\pgfplotmarksize) .. (-0.3118\pgfplotmarksize,1.0737\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (-0.1920\pgfplotmarksize,0.8813\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (-0.1153\pgfplotmarksize,0.6618\pgfplotmarksize) .. (0.0194\pgfplotmarksize,0.4801\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (0.2491\pgfplotmarksize,0.7120\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (0.4404\pgfplotmarksize,0.9798\pgfplotmarksize) .. (0.6716\pgfplotmarksize,1.2102\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (0.7601\pgfplotmarksize,1.2826\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (0.8675\pgfplotmarksize,1.1351\pgfplotmarksize) .. (0.9475\pgfplotmarksize,1.2444\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (1.1035\pgfplotmarksize,1.1629\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (1.0140\pgfplotmarksize,1.0177\pgfplotmarksize) .. (0.9191\pgfplotmarksize,0.9279\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (0.6837\pgfplotmarksize,0.6417\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (0.4642\pgfplotmarksize,0.3430\pgfplotmarksize) .. (0.2408\pgfplotmarksize,0.0475\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (0.3855\pgfplotmarksize,-0.2598\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (0.5445\pgfplotmarksize,-0.5609\pgfplotmarksize) .. (0.6685\pgfplotmarksize,-0.8774\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (0.6706\pgfplotmarksize,-0.9845\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (0.5386\pgfplotmarksize,-1.0399\pgfplotmarksize) .. (0.5409\pgfplotmarksize,-1.1513\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (0.4364\pgfplotmarksize,-1.3325\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (0.3201\pgfplotmarksize,-1.0970\pgfplotmarksize) .. (0.2551\pgfplotmarksize,-1.0079\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (0.1347\pgfplotmarksize,-0.8324\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (0.0259\pgfplotmarksize,-0.6485\pgfplotmarksize) .. (-0.0985\pgfplotmarksize,-0.4762\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (-0.2106\pgfplotmarksize,-0.5277\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (-0.2609\pgfplotmarksize,-0.6763\pgfplotmarksize) .. (-0.3397\pgfplotmarksize,-0.7730\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (-0.5313\pgfplotmarksize,-1.0592\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (-0.7140\pgfplotmarksize,-1.3513\pgfplotmarksize) .. (-0.8980\pgfplotmarksize,-1.6422\pgfplotmarksize) .. controls (-0.9557\pgfplotmarksize,-1.7528\pgfplotmarksize) and
  (-1.1546\pgfplotmarksize,-1.8080\pgfplotmarksize) .. (-1.2271\pgfplotmarksize,-1.6880\pgfplotmarksize) -- (-1.2410\pgfplotmarksize,-1.6636\pgfplotmarksize) --
  (-1.2410\pgfplotmarksize,-1.6636\pgfplotmarksize) -- cycle;
}
```

[image]